# Why does std::array not have an constructor that takes a value for the array to be filled with?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray

Is the absence of

```
std::array<T,size>::array(const T& value);
```

an oversight? It seems mighty useful to me, and dynamic containers (like `std::vector`) do have a similar constructor.

I am fully aware of

```
std::array<T,size>::fill(const T& value);
```

but that is not a constructor, and the memory will be zeroed out first. What if I want all `-1`'s like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890598/how-to-initialize-all-elements-in-an-array-to-the-same-number-in-c)?

Comment: "and the memory will be zeroed out first"

are you sure this is true?

Comment: It won't be zeroed out first, unless you ask for it.

Comment: Besides the *aggregate*-argument from all the answers, there could also be a more conceptual reasoning. A fill-constructor would probably hide the fact that it isn't really constructing the individual elements. It will first and foremost invoke the aggregate initialization and *then* copy the value into the elements, it can't copy-construct the elements right away (in contrast to, say a `std::vector`). So since it would always be equivalent to `array(); array.fill();`, omitting the constructor in the first place doesn't hide this fact.

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497122/how-to-initialize-stdarrayt-n-elegantly-if-t-is-not-default-constructible

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`std::array` is, by design, an aggregate, so has no user-declared constructors.

As you say, you could use `fill` after default constructing. Since it's an aggregate, default construction won't zero the memory, but will leave it uninitialised (if the contained type is trivially initialisable).

Comment: So [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is wrong? It says explicitly that the array's elements are default-initialized.

Comment: Default-initialization is no-init for PODs, and default-constructor for everything else I believe - depending on the point of declaration.

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, they'll be default-initialised, not value-initialised. So if they are trivially initialisable, then they'll be left uninitialied.

Comment: Ah yes. That still remains a very naughty part of the standard IMO which draws a distinction between user and built-in types `:/`

Comment: @rubenvb The primitive types all have trivial default-initialization. User-defined types can behave in the same way if desired. That's not distinction, it's consistency.

Answer (score 25):

Note that you can efficiently simulate this type of constructor by taking advantage of the fact that array is not zero-initialized, and has a copy constructor and do.

```
template <size_t N, class T>
array<T,N> make_array(const T &v) {
    array<T,N> ret;
    ret.fill(v);
    return ret;
}

auto a = make_array<20>('z');
```

Comment: let's not bloat the call site with unneeded template parameters `;-)`.

Comment: `char` can be inferred, so you can just write `make_array<20>('z')`  instead of `make_array<20,char>('z')`

Comment: @Nawaz oh, even better. I should have asked why there is no `make_array` instead `:-)`

Comment: Is return-value optimisation guaranteed here? Or is it better to return a rvalue reference?

Comment: @Walter: You couldn't return a reference of any sort, because you'd return a reference to a local variable.

Comment: Arrays larger than `2^31` on systems with 32 bit ints are not supported :(

Comment: @Walter: Yes return-value optimization is guaranteed when the variable is constructed in the same scope and then returned by copy. The compiler should automatically use move semantics since C++11/14.

Comment: This isn't going to work when `T` is not default constructible, and that's when you need the fill constructor badly.

Comment: @ChrisBeck, yes, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72760156/225186

Answer (score 16):

You may use `std::index sequence` for that:

```
namespace detail
{

    template <typename T, std::size_t...Is>
    constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>
    make_array(const T& value, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return {{(static_cast<void>(Is), value)...}};
    }
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
constexpr std::array<T, N> make_array(const T& value)
{
    return detail::make_array(value, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Jd2bXQ)

`std::make_index_sequence` is C++14, but can be implemented in C++11.

`static_cast<void>(Is)` is to handle evil `operator,` that `T` might provide.

Comment: This is the most useful answer, it works also when `T` is not default constructible, which is when the other answers fall short.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Could not agree more. That was precisely the case for me and I was getting frustrated with the other answers. Goes to show that up-votes ain't everything.

Comment: Because of using template recursion, this won't compile for large arrays. If I need a million-element array of T with no default constructor am I out of luck? Even a C array would work for me.

Comment: @MichałBrzozowski: `std::index_sequence` might be implemented with logarithm instantiation instead of linear. and compiler might have *"intrinsics"* to do only one instantiation. Then, there are no longer recursion.

Comment: That still doesn't work very well, because the resulting binary size is linear with respect to the size of the array - there is a dedicated piece of code for initializing each element in the array. In the usual case when elements are default constructed, this is done in a runtime loop.

Comment: @MichałBrzozowski: You can still switch to `std::vector`, and `reserve` whole size and `emplace_back` in a loop.As for a million-element, stack would be problematic as memory limited in practice.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, it is not `std::array<T>`, it is `std::array<T,N>` where `N` is compile time constant integral expression.

Second, `std::array` is made aggregate by design. So it doesn't have anything which makes it non-aggregate, which is why it doesn't have constructor... and destructor, virtual functions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I took answer from [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923683/why-does-stdarray-not-have-an-constructor-that-takes-a-value-for-the-array-to/41259045#:%7E:text=at%209%3A16-,Jarod42,-184k13) and made an extension to be able to use variable amount of Constructor arguments and also added automatic indexer as a first arg:

```
namespace detail {
  template <typename T, std::size_t... Seq, typename... Args>
  constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Seq)> make_array(std::index_sequence<Seq...>, Args &... args)
  {
    return {{(static_cast<void>(Seq), T(Seq, args...))...}};
  }
}  // namespace detail

template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename... Args>
constexpr std::array<T, N> make_array(Args &... args)
{
  return detail::make_array<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>(), args...);
}

class myClass {
  myClass(unsigned int i, float a, std::string b, int c):... {};
}
```

Usage:

```
auto myArray = make_array<myClass, 64>(a, b, c);
```