# 2D double array not being filled up with value

Tags: c++11, multidimensional-array, double

In my program, I am trying to fill a 2-dimensional array of doubles with the constant value of `DBL_MAX`. However, when I debug my code, I find that the array is filled with the value of 0, not `DBL_MAX`, even after I step past the array-filling code. Is there something I am doing wrong?

**Here is my code for filling the double 2d array**

```
double array[150][150];
memset(array, DBL_MAX, sizeof(array));
```

Comment: memset(array, DBL_MAX, sizeof(array[0][0]) * m * n); m and n would be the 150

Comment: I am curious if ur compiler allows for this: int array[N][M] = {DBL_MAX};

Comment: @OmidCompSCI I tried `{DBL_MAX}`, but it only fills the `array[0][0]` element. Also, `memset(array, DBL_MAX, sizeof(array[0][0]) * m * n);` didn't work.

Comment: Try: memset(array, DBL_MAX, sizeof(int [150][150]));

Comment: @OmidCompSCI hmmm, that didn't work either. Thanks for the tips though

Comment: No prob, hopefully messin with those it might work. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memset` sets each byte to the value provided. However you actually want to set each `double`.

You can use:

```
double array[150][150];
std::fill_n(&array[0][0], 150 * 150, DBL_MAX);   // #include <algorithm>
```

It is also possible to use template metaprogramming to generate code basically equivalent to `double array[150][150] = { DBL_MAX, DBL_MAX, DBL_MAX,` .... , [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18497122/1505939) for ideas.

Answer (score 2):

`memset()` is simply the wrong tool for the job here.

it's declared as:

```
void* memset( void* dest, int ch, std::size_t count );
```

Where `ch` will be assigned to each byte of data. If you test what `DBL_MAX` is, when casted to int, you can confirm why you are getting zeros:

```
int x = DBL_MAX;
std::cout << x << "\n"; // prints 0
```

You could mess with casting and `std::fill`, but that would look pretty bad in my opinion, I think you are better off using a simple double-loop and let the compiler take care of optimizing it for you:

```
for(auto& l : array) {
  for (auto& c : l) {
    c = DBL_MAX;
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Since you've tagged this as C++11, a general comment: unless you are interacting with APIs and interfaces that work directly on memory, you really should not be thinking in terms of "memory" when writing modern C++ code. Even when dealing with the core data types, it's almost always better to treat them as objects. If you are using any of the old `mem...` interfaces, odds are you are tackling your problem from the wrong angle.