# Initializing an std::array of non-default-constructible elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, default-constructor, stdarray

Suppose type `foo_t` with a named constructor idiom, `make_foo()`. Now, I want to have exactly 123 foo's - no more, no less. So, I'm thinking about an `std::array<foo_t, 123>`. Now, if `foo_t` were default-constructible, I would write:

```
std::array<foo_t, 123> pity_the_foos;
std::generate(
    std::begin(pity_the_foos), std::end(pity_the_foos),
    []() { return make_foo(); }
);
```

and Bob's my uncle, right? Unfortunately... `foo_t` has no default ctor.

How should I initialize my array, then? Do I need to use some variadic template expansion voodoo perhaps?

**Note:** Answers may use anything in C++11, C++14 or C++17 if that helps at all.

Comment: will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19016627/8414561

Comment: @DevNull: Yes, but - how idiomatic is that array generator snippet you have there?

Comment: define "idiomatic"? :)

Comment: @DevNull: There's a tag for that... the idiom that the most people use; the "common, appropriate thing to do". Also - that looks like it needs some fixup to use C++14 integer sequences, am I right?

Comment: well, the answer shows that it seems to be pretty idiomatic

Comment: Very similar (except generator versus repeat-copy): [c++ - How to initialize std::array<T, n> elegantly if T is not default constructible? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497122/how-to-initialize-stdarrayt-n-elegantly-if-t-is-not-default-constructible)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The usual.

```
template<size_t...Is>
std::array<foo_t, sizeof...(Is)> make_foos(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return { ((void)Is, make_foo())... };
}

template<size_t N>
std::array<foo_t, N> make_foos() {
    return make_foos(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Comment: That index sequence does keep popping up, doesn't it... although, really, I shouldn't even need the integer sequence in my case, just any tuple of length N.