# Generate initializer list of varying size depending on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, initializer-list

I have a class that contains an array of objects `T` without a default constructor. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Param {
    int x;
};

struct A {
    A(const Param &p) {
        std::cout << p.x << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T, int n>
struct Array {
    T data[n];
                                 /*     n times     */
    Array(const Param &p) : data{/* T(p), ..., T(p) */} { }
};

int main() {
    Param p{42};
    Array<A, 3> arr(p);
    return 0;
}
```

I am looking for a way to initialize the `data` field using a varying size initializer list of elements `T(p)` containing exactly `n` elements. I have a feeling that it can be achieved by some construction like `std::make_index_sequence`, but I did not find anything appropriate.

Comment: If you're looking for a dynamically sized array, take a look at vectors

Comment: @emsimpson92 No, I do not want to allocate data on heap. It's a fixed-size array with size known at compile time

Comment: strictly C++11? No C++14?

Comment: Partial dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899731/initializing-an-stdarray-of-non-default-constructible-elements I'm trying to find a more exact one

Comment: @max66 c++14 is ok too

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, that would probably work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you can use a delegating contructor, `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` and rewrite `Array` as follows (Edit: answer improved by SergeyA and Rakete1111; thanks!)

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Array
 {
    T data[N];

    template <std::size_t ... Is>
    Array (Param const & p, std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
       : data { ((void)Is, T{p}) ... }
     { }

    Array(const Param &p) : Array{p, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}}
     { }
 };
```

Maybe you can make `private` the new constructor.

Comment: There is no need for `get_val` in the example, instead just use `data { ((void)Is, T{P})...}`

Comment: @SergeyA Wow! Didn't think of that. `data{((void)Is, T{P})...}`, it's safer ;)

Comment: @SergeyA - I was looking a way to avoid that ugly function; it was so simple and elegant! Thanks.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - maybe not safer (for a `std::size_t` isn't defined in a dangerous way the comma operator) but avoid an annoying warning. Thanks.

Comment: @max66 what stops me from defining a `bool operator,(std::size_t, T)` ;)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - well... that `(void)` avoid an annoying warning.

Comment: @max66 templates + comma = asking for trouble :)