# Class with all automatically-generated constructors/operators deleted can still be returned from a function?

Tags: c++, return-value, c++17, deleted-functions

Recently, I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46899787/1021959) which describes how to initialize a `std::array` of non-default-constructible elements.  I was not so surprised because that answer clearly doesn't do any default-constructing.

Instead, it is constructing a temporary `std::array` using aggregate initialization, then moving (if the move constructor is available) or copying into the named variable when the function returns.  So we only need either the move constructor or copy constructor to be available.

*Or so I thought...*

Then came this piece of code which confounded me:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    foo(int x) : x(x) {}
    foo() = delete;
    foo(const foo&) = delete;
    foo& operator=(const foo&) = delete;
    foo(foo&&) = delete;
    foo& operator=(foo&&) = delete;
};

foo make_foo(int x) {
    return foo(x);
}

int main() {
    foo f = make_foo(1);
    foo g(make_foo(2));
}
```

All the five special member constructors/operators are explicitly deleted, so now I shouldn't be able to construct my object from a return value, correct?

**Wrong.**

To my surprise, this compiles in gcc (with C++17)!

Why does this compile?  Clearly to return a `foo` from the function `make_foo()`, we have to construct a `foo`.  Which means that in the `main()` function we are assigning or constructing a `foo` from the returned `foo`.  How is that possible?!

Comment: Try compiling with the `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` flags to observe different results.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of [guaranteed copy elision](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html) (new to C++17. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043319/2069064)).

```
foo make_foo(int x) {
    return foo(x);
}

int main() {
    foo f = make_foo(1);
    foo g(make_foo(2));
}
```

In all of these cases, you're initializing a `foo` from a prvalue of type `foo`, so we just ignore all the intermediate objects and directly initialize the outermost object from the actual initializer. This is exactly equivalent to:

```
foo f(1);
foo g(2);
```

We don't even consider move constructors here - so the fact that they're deleted doesn't matter. The specific rule is [[dcl.init]/17.6.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.1) - it's only *after* this point that we consider the constructors and perform overload resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that pre-C++17 (before guaranteed copy elision), you might already return that object with braced-init-lists:

```
foo make_foo(int x) {
    return {x}; // Require non explicit foo(int).
                // Doesn't copy/move.
}
```

But usage would be different:

```
foo&& f = make_foo(1);
foo&& g(make_foo(2));
```

Comment: Is the lifetime of `foo&& f` extended in the same way as `const foo& f`?