# Call user defined constructor on elements in std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization, stdarray

I have a simple example where I create an `std::array` of some number of Foo elements:

```
struct Foo
{
     Foo(int bar=0) : m_bar(bar) 
     {
       // Code depending on the value of bar
     }

     int m_bar;
};

const unsigned int num = // get array size 
std::array<Foo, num> fooArr;
```

When I use the initialiser list in the constructor `m_bar(bar)` this sets all the `Foo.m_bar` to `0` (as this is the default constructor parameter value). If I don't do that then it is full with garbage values.

My question is how do I pass in another value different from the default one to the constructor of every element in the array without knowing the array size before hand?

I tried using a init list when creating the array, like so: `std::array<Foo, 5> fooArr{3}` but that only sets the first element's `m_bar` to `3`.

Comment: What about fooArr{{1,2,3,4,5}}?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't very clear but I shouldn't know the array size before hand, to be able to do that. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: In Cppreference there is this example: std::array<std::string, 2> a3 = { std::string("a"), "b" };
Is it what you are searching for?

Comment: Do you know the size in compile time or is it defined by a preprocessor define?

Comment: @G.Rassovsky: Probably that's not exactly match your needs, but you can call std::array::fill.

Comment: Well, you have to know the array size somewhere...

Comment: `std::array<Foo, 5>` and "*without knowing the array size*" make things unclear.

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree, will correct that.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923683/why-does-stdarray-not-have-an-constructor-that-takes-a-value-for-the-array-to - though for question the aspect of avoiding default construction wasn't as relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should simply default-construct the `std::array` then use its [`fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill) method to populate it with a fixed value.  Many compilers can optimize this effectively, so you won't pay for the "extra" initialization.

To satisfy your use case, the code would look something like this:

```
fooArr.fill(Foo(3));
```

Comment: The problem with that (unless i misunderstand what you mean) is that if I have code in the constructor of Foo() which depends on the value of size it will still get 0's wont it?

Comment: I would even wrap it up in a convenience function to use it in initialization.

Comment: @G.Rassovsky What is `size` and how does `Foo` know anything about it?

Comment: arrrgh, my bad i meant to say *bar* not *size*, sorry.

Comment: You'd do `fooArr.fill(Foo(3))` to satisfy your example.  `bar` would be `3` in the anonymous temporary `Foo`, which would then be copied to all the array elements.

Comment: @G.Rassovsky Well, the state of an object after assignment should be the same as it is if you  had constructed it in the same way as the object it is assigned from. If this isn't the case, then this king of thing will always be problematic.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I see now what you mean, that worked and is quite simple. Can you please also include the usage in your answer above so it is easier for anyone reading it?

Comment: @G.Rassovsky: Great, I've added the example code to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Make an `integer_sequence` with N elements, and build the array with a pack expansion. This is more useful if your default constructor does nontrivial work or doesn't exist.

```
template<std::size_t N, class T, std::size_t... Ns>
std::array<T, N> make_repeating_array(const T& value, std::index_sequence<Ns...>) {
    return {(void(Ns), value)... };
}

template<std::size_t N, class T>
std::array<T, N> make_repeating_array(const T& value) {
    return make_repeating_array<N>(value, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Use as

```
std::array<Foo, num> fooArr = make_repeating_array<num>(Foo(5));
```

Comment: I appreciate the example even though i'm not exactly sure how it works. I've accepted John Zwinck's answer as it is simpler and works for my case but please keep yours up as I can imagine this being more useful in more complex situations.

Comment: What is the `(void(Ns), value)` for?

Comment: @xtofl Essentially, it repeats `value` `sizeof...(Ns)` (which is `N`) times. The `,` is the comma operator.

Comment: Can the array size be determined from ```sizeof...(Ns)``` in ```make_repeating_array``` ?