# How to initialize a template sized array?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to initialize a template sized array of objects with no default constructors, as shown in following code :

```
#include <array>

template<std::size_t N>
class Foo
{
    public:
        class Bar
        {
                Foo<N> & _super;

            public:
                Bar(Foo<N> *super) :
                    _super(*super)
                {
                }
        };

        std::array<Bar, N>  _array;

        Foo(void) :
            _array{{}} // We need {this, ...} N times
        {
        }
};


int main(void)
{
    Foo<3>  foo;
    (void)foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it a way to say : "I want an array of N objects, all initialized with this same parameter" ? I think there is a way with the template meta programming, but I cannot figure how to do it.

Comment: Shouldn't `Bar`'s constructor be `Bar(Foo<N> &super) : _super(super)`? Or member `Foo<N> & _super` should be `Foo<N> * _super`?

Comment: @flatmouse Does not change anything, no ? I could write it and construct Bar as follow `Bar(*this)` ; but that does not help solving the question.

Comment: Ah ok, you are taking a pointer which is then deferenced to initialize the reference member. I was trying to understand. I get it now.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923683/why-does-stdarray-not-have-an-constructor-that-takes-a-value-for-the-array-to

Comment: @NathanOliver I cannot see how it is a duplicate...

Comment: @Boiethios Part of my boilerplate.  I forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just keep adding one `this` at a time until you have `N` of them, at which point you just initialize `_array`:

```
    Foo()
    : Foo(this)
    { }

private:
    template <class... T, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(T) < N), void*> = nullptr>
    Foo(T... args)
    : Foo(args..., this)
    { }

    template <class... T, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(T) == N), void*> = nullptr>
    Foo(T... args)
    : _array{{args...}}
    { }
```

Comment: @Boiethios The `index_sequence` approach is better.

Comment: Is it possible to write this code in C++11 (`enable_if_t` is C++14) ? For example with a template parameter `size_t I` that will decrease and a specialized version `<0>` ? I try to do this, but I have trouble with the writing of templates.

Comment: @Boiethios `enable_if_t` is just an alias template, you could just copy the definition in C++11.

Answer (score 9):

Everything is possible with the little help from `make_index_sequence`:

```
   Foo() : Foo(std::make_index_sequence<N>()) {} 
   template <size_t... I> Foo(std::index_sequence<I...> ) : _array{((void)I, this)...} {}
```

Notice the comma operator (,) in the `_array` constructor - courtesy of @Quentin (as opposed to function call).

Comment: You can replace the function invocation with a comma operator : `_array{(I, this)...}` :)

Comment: Sure ! I didn't want to post an answer that be identical to yours, save for this tweak.

Comment: That seems a really convenient way to do this, but that necessitates the C++14. Is it possible in C++11 ?

Comment: @Boiethios, you can easily implement make_index_sequence in C++11. Let me post the code.

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks. It's because the compiler we use is C++11.

Comment: `((void)I, this)` removes the warning

Comment: @SergeyA I'd like to read your `make_index_sequence implementation` as explanation of it, but I think the @Barry version will be shortest. So I will ask for a make_index_sequence explanation in another question, and you will post this answer as its answer.

Comment: @Boiethios If you google C++11 make_index_sequence, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17426611/2069064) is the 2nd result.