# Initialize template<size_t N> std::array<char, N> with ASCII spaces?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates, constructor

We can initialize, say, `std::array<char, 3>` with `= { ' ', ' ', ' ' }` but what if the size is given by a template parameter `N` ? Can't we do something like [`std::string::string(size_type count, CharT ch)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) which fills the instance with the given `ch` ?

Should I perhaps look at [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) ?

Comment: You can always [fill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) the array after definition.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are talking about only non-`const` arrays. With `const`, it would become as ugly as `const std::array<char, N> arr([&arr, ch] { std::remove_const_t<decltype(arr)> tmp; std::fill_n(tmp.begin(), tmp.size(), ch); return tmp; }());` Well, it's doable, but...

Answer (score 3):

You may use index sequence for that:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t...Is>
std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> make_array(const T& value, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return {{(Is, value)...}};
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
std::array<T, N> make_array(const T& value)
{
    return make_array(value, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/fnTX1T)

Comment: Interesting trick to map `Is` to a sequence of `value`s, but if we need to introduce a helper function, it doesn't offer much benefits over `fill_n()` proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923683/why-does-stdarray-not-have-an-constructor-that-takes-a-value-for-the-array-to

Comment: @nodakai: It does the initialization once, but indeed, the two solutions are mostly equivalent.