# std::make_unique causes big slowdown?

Tags: c++, stl, g++, c++14, clang++

I have recently started to modernize my C++ codebase by using C++14 instead of C++11.

After replacing a single occurrence of `std::unique_ptr.reset(new ...)` with `std::make_unique` from C++14 I realized that my test suite (which consists of about 30 C++ test programs) ran about 50% slower.

**Old C++11 code (fast):**

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo(size_t size)
    {
        array.reset(new char[size]);
    }
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> array;
};
```

**New C++14 code (slow):**

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo(size_t size)
    {
        array = std::make_unique<char[]>(size);
    }
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> array;
};
```

Both GCC and Clang run much slower using the C++14 code with `std::make_unique`. When I test both versions using valgrind it reports that both the C++11 and C++14 code use the same amount of allocations and the same amount of allocated memory and there are no memory leaks.

When I look at the generated assembly of the test programs above I have the suspicion that the C++14 version using `std::make_unique` resets the memory after the allocation using memset. The C++11 version does not do this:

**C++11 assembly (GCC 7.4, x64)**

```
main:
sub rsp, 8
movsx rdi, edi
call operator new[](unsigned long)
mov rdi, rax
call operator delete[](void*)
xor eax, eax
add rsp, 8
ret
```

**C++14 assembly (GCC 7.4, x64)**

```
main:
push rbx
movsx rbx, edi
mov rdi, rbx
call operator new[](unsigned long)
mov rcx, rax
mov rax, rbx
sub rax, 1
js .L2
lea rax, [rbx-2]
mov edx, 1
mov rdi, rcx
cmp rax, -1
cmovge rdx, rbx
xor esi, esi
call memset
mov rcx, rax
.L2:
mov rdi, rcx
call operator delete[](void*)
xor eax, eax
pop rbx
ret
```

Questions:

Is initializing memory a known feature of `std::make_unique`? If not what else could explain the performance slowdown I am experiencing?

Comment: This does indeed seem like an "I didn't as for this, why am I paying for it" type of situation...

Comment: @Richard Compiler explorer does reproduce the issue even with -O3. Your example does not show the issue because your size is hardcoded to 10.

Comment: Compiler explorer link of std::make_unique issue: https://godbolt.org/g/7URbfP

Answer (score 23):

> Is initializing memory a known feature of `std::make_unique`?

It depends on what you mean by "known." But yeah, that is the difference between your cases. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), the `make_unique<T>(size)` call does:

> ```
> unique_ptr<T>(new typename std::remove_extent<T>::type[size]())
> //                                                         ~~~~
> ```

This is how it is [specified](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.create#4).

`new char[size]` allocates memory and default-initializes it. `new char[size]()` allocates memory and value-initializes it, which zero-initializes in the case of `char`. By default, a lot of the things in the standard library will value-initialize and not default initialize.

Likewise, `make_unique<T>()` does `new T()` and not `new T`... `make_unique<char>()` gives you 0, `new char` gives you an indeterminate value.

As a similar example, if I want to have a `vector<char>` resize to an *uninitialized* buffer of a given size (to be immediately populated by something else), I have to either use my own allocator or use a type that isn't `char` which lies about its initialization.

---

C++20 will introduce new helper functions to alleviate this problem, courtesy of [P11020R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1020r1.html):

- `make_unique_default_init`
- `make_shared_default_init`
- `allocate_shared_default_init`

Whereas `make_unique<T>()` would do `new T()`, these do `new T`. That is, there is no extra zeroing. In the specific case of OP, `std::make_unique_default_init<char[]>(size)` is what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by that last bit about `char` lying about its own initialization?

Comment: @rubenvb e.g. `struct my_char { my_char() { /* nothing */ } char c; };`

Comment: Forgive me for being thick on a Friday afternoon, but where is the lie in that fragment?

Comment: @rubenvb in the sense that `my_char`'s constructor does not actually initialise a `my_char` into a defined state.

Comment: @Richard That is not lying. That is default initialization for fundamental types and aggregates. I bumped into this a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17923683/256138

Comment: @rubenvb: I suppose the lie is just that a constructor like `my_char()` usually makes you believe that it takes care of correct initialisation of all data members.

Comment: @rubenvb I didn't say it was, Barry did. Surely you understand why he refers to it as such? We don't normally enjoy having objects constructed in an undefined state.

Comment: Yet every time you type `char c;` you get exactly the same undefined state initialization... Granted, it's surprising, but it's part of the pay for what you use thing.

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, because `char` is a fundamental type. When I type `std::string s;` or `std::vector<int> v;`, I (correctly) expect to get a defined state.

Comment: Well, then you just messed up `my_char::my_char` IMO.

Comment: @rubenvb • it's not messed up, it's an intentional lie so as not to pay the initialization performance hit for when it is not desired.