# Initializing a std::array with a constant value

Tags: c++, initialization, stdarray

I need to initialize all elements of a `std::array` with a constant value, like it can be done with `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v(10, 7);    // OK
  std::array<int, 10> a(7);     // does not compile, pretty frustrating
}
```

Is there a way to do this elegantly?

Right now I'm using this:

```
std::array<int, 10> a;
for (auto & v : a)
  v = 7;
```

but I'd like to avoid using explicit code for the initialisation.

Comment: Related to [Why does std::array not have an constructor that takes a value for the array to be filled with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923683/why-does-stdarray-not-have-an-constructor-that-takes-a-value-for-the-array-to)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

With `std::index_sequence`, you might do:

```cpp
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
    constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>
    create_array(T value, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        // cast Is to void to remove the warning: unused value
        return {{(static_cast<void>(Is), value)...}};
    }
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
constexpr std::array<T, N> create_array(const T& value)
{
    return detail::create_array(value, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

With usage

```
auto a = create_array<10 /*, int*/>(7); // auto is std::array<int, 10>
```

Which, contrary to `std::fill` solution, handle non default constructible types.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution for my needs.  Very similar to the non compiling `std::array<int, 10> a(7)` which becomes `auto a = create_array<10, int>(7)` or even `auto a = create_array<10>(7)`

Comment: What's the difference of all this to just a method with a `foreach` inside?

Comment: @mFeinstein: *"contrary to `std::fill` solution, handle **non default constructible type**."*.

Comment: So `std::fill` is a `foreach`?

Comment: Your `foreach` or for-range to set value would be equivalent to what `fill` will do.

Comment: I see... well, I am not as experienced in C++, so this answer uses a lot of concepts that I am not familiar with

Answer (score 35):

Alas not; `std::array` supports *aggregate initialisation* but that's not enough here.

Fortunately you can use `std::fill`, or even `std::array<T,N>::fill`, which, from C++20 *is* elegant as the latter becomes `constexpr`.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill

Answer (score 29):

You can do as following

```
std::array<int, 10> a; 
a.fill(2/*or any other value*/);
```

Or use `std::fill` from algorithms header file.
To include algorithms header file use

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write out the actual code. This is something I don't do often enough: Stack Overflow works best when there are multiple answers to choose from.

Comment: @Bathsheba no problem mate)

Comment: @Bathsheba I am writing this from a phone so I haven't seen that you already answered the question

Comment: I'm glad - you should answer answer a question if you believe you have something to say that, perhaps, hasn't already been said. I think this answer is more useful in some ways than mine.

Answer (score 6):

Since C++17 you can write a constexpr function to efficiently set up the array, since the element accessors are constexpr now. This method will also work for various other schemes of setting up initial values:

```
#include <array>

template<typename T, size_t N>
constexpr auto make_array(T value) -> std::array<T, N>
{
    std::array<T, N> a{};
    for (auto& x : a)
        x = value;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    auto arr = make_array<int, 10>(7);
}
```

Comment: Requires default constructible `T` though.

Comment: Also, no need to value initialize the `std::array` before initializing with `value`.

Comment: @ggg no harm in following good general habits

Comment: @M.M You don't pay for what you don't use.

Comment: @ggg you do pay for errors due to uninitialized variables in other situations

Answer (score 4):

As said before, the `fill` solution doesn't work for non-default constructible types.
The `index_sequence` solution is correct but a bit verbose.

Given a value `t` (of any type) and a compile constant `N`, the following evaluates to the desired solution in one line.

```
std::apply([&](auto... dummy) {return std::array{(dummy, t)...};}, std::array<int, N>{});
```

See full code here: https://godbolt.org/z/jcq4fqMsE

This solution can be applied to C++17 and with some modifications to earlier C++ versions.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::array` type is an aggregate that supports list-initialization:

```
std::array<int, 10> a{2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
```

It also supports aggregate-initialization:

```
std::array<int, 10> a = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
```

This is inconvenient and error-prone for long arrays, and you would be better off using a solution like Jarod42’s for those.

Comment: This is inconvenient and error-prone for _any_ array length.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The accepted answer is great and I upvoted it. It’s also kind of overkill for an array of three elements. The others don’t work for a `constexpr std::array`. So this technique is sometimes appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

From **C++20** the `ranges` have `fill`

```
std::array<int, 10> a2;
std::ranges::fill(a2, 10);
```

Also, if the array is a small (for larger ones it may look odd), from **C++17** (argument deduction)

```
auto a = std::array{2,2,2,2};
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fairly easily by creating a function template that return the required array as shown below. It is even possible to initialize the array at compile time!(see the c++17 example demo given at the end of the answer).

```
template<std::size_t N> std::array<int, N> make_array(int val)
{
    std::array<int, N> tempArray{};    //create local array
    for(int &elem:tempArray)           //populate it 
    {
        elem = val;                     
    }
    return tempArray;                   //return it
}
int main()
{
    //---------------------V-------->number of elements  
    auto arr  = make_array<10>(7);
    //------------------------^---->value of element to be initialized with

    
    //lets confirm if all objects have the expected value 
    for(const auto &elem: arr)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl; //prints all 7 
    }
    
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mv7P3oxME)

---

Note also that it is even possible to do this at compile time with C++17. [Demo C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/MYcca9PvP)