# Create std::array<T, N> from constructor argument list

Tags: c++, initialization, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, stdarray

The desired behaviour is that of `emplace` called `N` times.

Very similar to this question [Initializing a std::array with a constant value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57756557/11998382). Except instead of calling the copy constructor given some `T`, you are given some argument list for which you call the corresponding constructor of `T`.

Pseudo code:

```cpp
template <typename ...Args>
std::array<T, N> create_array(Args&&... args)
{
    return { T(args...), T(args...), .... };
}
```

For example, this is necessary when `T` has members that are (smart) pointers and you want these pointers to reference unique objects.

Comment: I would change signature to take generator: `template <std::size_t N, typename Generator> auto create_array_from_generator(Generator gen) -> std::array<std::decay_t<decltype(gen())>, N>; // return {{gen(), gen(), gen(), ..}};`

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks, I don't know why there's a push back on SO for using `std::array` over `std::vector`. You can read the size from just the type. But it just hit me that I should be doing this for my own types (i.e. packing all the compile time information into the type, rather than passing it through the constructor). Solves an irritating workflow pattern I have atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jarod commented that this should be implemented with a generator taking the index, and with c++20 templated lambdas we can do away with the helper function

```cpp
template <std::size_t N, typename Generator>
auto make_array(Generator gen)
{
    return [&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) -> std::array<std::decay_t<decltype(gen(std::size_t{}))>, N>
    {
        return { {(gen(I))...} };
    }(std::make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, N>{});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5qGbYWjEh

Answer (score 0):

Modifying this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57757301/11998382), I came up with:

```cpp
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is, typename ...V>
    constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>
        create_array(std::index_sequence<Is...>, V&&... values)
    {
        // cast Is to void to remove the warning: unused value
        return { {(static_cast<void>(Is), T(values...))...} };
    }
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename ...V>
constexpr std::array<T, N> create_array(V&&... values)
{
    return detail::create_array<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>(), std::forward<V>(values)...);
}
```