# Can't figure out how to create a two priority_queue with lambda and an array intitilizer

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I have the following code that works

```
auto comp = [&](const auto &x, const auto &y) {
    return a[x] < a[y] || (a[x] == a[y] && x < y);
};
priority_queue <int, vector <int>, decltype(comp)> q(comp); // works
```

And I want to create two of the PQs here like this:

```
auto comp = [&](const auto &x, const auto &y) {
    return a[x] < a[y] || (a[x] == a[y] && x < y);
};
priority_queue <int, vector <int>, decltype(comp)> q(comp)[2]; // doesn't work
```

so I can't seem to understand what are the semantics here.

For simple PQ declaring an array of them works:

```
priority_queue <int> q[2]; // works :(
```

Just looking for way to create two lambda queues with indexing q[0] and q[1], but can't seem grasp documentation on it.

*Edit: Thank you everyone!

Could I ask follow up here: what to do if I wanted more queues, some q[N]?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(comp)> q[2] = {priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(comp)>(comp), priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(comp)>(comp)};` ?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Though I wish there was a simpler way. Can I ask here : what if I wanted to have more than 2 queues, some N queues?

Comment: I guess you could write it in a vector and then emplace_back elements N times in a for loop

Answer (score 3):

`... q(comp)` calls the constructor. If you want an array, just adding `[2]` after that does not make sense.

What you want is something like `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(comp)> q[2]`, except you need to initialize the two objects. Here is one way to do it:

```
using CustomQueue = std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(comp)>;
CustomQueue q[2] { CustomQueue(comp), CustomQueue(comp) };
```

Because the constructor of `std::priority_queue` that takes a comparator is explicit, you cannot use `{ {comp}, {comp} }`.

Answering the edit: if you want `n` queues, you can always rely on `std::vector` instead of an array:

```
std::vector<CustomQueue> q(n, CustomQueue(comp));
```

If you really want an array, and `n` is known at compile time, then you can do something like this:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
    constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>
    create_array(T value, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        // cast Is to void to remove the warning: unused value
        return {{(static_cast<void>(Is), value)...}};
    }
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
constexpr std::array<T, N> create_array(const T& value)
{
    return detail::create_array(value, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

// ...

auto q = create_array<20>(Queue(comp));
```

[Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57757301/3854570)

Answer (score 2):

The initializers of the array go into `{}` brackets after `[2]`. Furthermore the constructor you're attempting to use is `explicit`, so you need to mention the priority queue type in the initializer values as well:

```
auto comp = [&](const auto& x, const auto& y) {
    return a[x] < a[y] || (a[x] == a[y] && x < y);
};
using PriorityQueue = std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(comp)>;
PriorityQueue q[2]{ PriorityQueue(comp), PriorityQueue(comp) };
```