# Initialize an std::array of objects with non-trivial constructor

Tags: c++, stdarray

I have a class defined as

```cpp
class Edgelet
{
private:
    const int e_size;
    //Other private members...
public:
    //The constructor
    explicit Edgelet (int size, Color cl1 = Color::NA, Color cl2 = Color::NA);
    //Other public members...
```

As there is a *const* member in the class the default copy constructor is implicitly deleted by the compiler. It needs to be given an argument to initialize.

The problem comes in the class

```cpp
class Cube
{
private:
    std::array <Edgelet, 12> c_edgelets;
    //Other members...
public:
    //The constructor
    Cube(int size)
    
    //Other public members...
```

This class contains a *std::array* of the previous class objects. How do I initialize this array? The *size* parameter needs to be given to each element of *std::array* to initialize. I want to set each element of *std::array* as `Edgelet(size - 2)`.

I could, of course, use initializer list but as there are 12 elements and other parameters to the constructor than shown, the code is getting ugly. Besides I did that with a similar case with 6 elements instead of 12.

I also tried giving default values to parameters but as there is a *const* member the value can not be changed later on. I also tried looking into *std::initializer_list* but it seems you cannot add new elements to it (or maybe you can??). Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Related to [why-does-stdarray-not-have-an-constructor-that-takes-a-value-for-the-array-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923683/why-does-stdarray-not-have-an-constructor-that-takes-a-value-for-the-array-to).

Comment: General advice: Don't use (non-static) `const` data members in classes. If an internal value is meant to be immutable, enforce this property through the public API of your class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might write helper class:

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename T>
std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> make_array_impl(const T& def, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return {{(Is, void(), def)...}};
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
std::array<T, N> make_array(const T& def)
{
    return make_array_impl(def, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

and then

```
Cube(int size) : c_edgelets(make_array<12>(Edgelet(size - 2)) {}
```

Comment: Depending on what happens inside Edgelet constructor, might want to construct it in-place instead of copying.

Comment: I have not studied C++ upto templates but it seems I have no choice but to learn them first to implement this thing. Anyways thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If array members are not default constructible, you have to provide an initiailzer for each element.  Instead  of doing that, you can use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::array`.  `std::vector` has a constructor with the form of

```
constexpr vector( size_type count,
                  const T& value,
                  const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

that will construct `count` objects initialized with `value`.  That would make your code look like

```
class Cube
{
private:
    std::vector<Edgelet> c_edgelets;
    //Other members...
public:
    //The constructor
    Cube(int size) : c_edgelets(12, Edgelet(size - 2)) {}
    
    //Other public members...
};
```

Comment: Is there any method to do it with *std::array*? As the size is compile-time constant the use of  std::array is more natural instead of *std::vector*.

Comment: @Jatin Jarod42 just posted a way to do this with a `std::array`.

Comment: Could also be a use case for [boost::static_vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html)