# How to declare std::array when element type has no default constructor?

Tags: c++, stdarray

I have a circular buffer class whose constructor is:

```
template <class T>
class circular_buffer {
public:
    circular_buffer(size_t size) :
    buf(std::unique_ptr<T[]>(new T[size])),
    max_size(size)
{}
```

I want to create a std::array of these circular buffers. So I need a declaration that is something like:

```
std::array< circular_buffer<TMyType>, MAX_BUFFERS > bufferArray;
```

But that fails with error:

```
function was implicitly deleted because a data member 'std::array<circular_buffer<TMyType>,14>::_Elems' has either no appropriate default constructor or overload resolution was ambiguous
```

The reason seems obvious that I am providing no parameter for circular_buffer's constructor ('size').

How would I correct the declaration of bufferArray to specify 'size'?

Comment: Since you use a pointer to heap memory, why not just a `std::vector`?

Comment: @alexey-larionov The number of buffers is constant so an array seems more natural. Also, I need the code to be very fast and array may be faster than vector?

Comment: You can provide a default constructor for `circular_buffer`, and re-assign the value after creating the empty `array`. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/va5n4rhdT)

Comment: *Also, I need the code to be very fast and array may be faster than vector?*  Faster to use?  No.  Faster to create?  No.  Faster to destroy?  No.  Exist entirely on the stack?  Yes, a C style can do that; but you're not leveraging that capability here.  Not have any reallocations?  A `std::vector` can have its capacity reserved.  Not be dynamic and has a fixed size?  A `std::vector` can be resized to a fixed size.

Comment: The "performance" here falls down to how fast you can access an element. In your case assuming you have some `circular_buffer cb;`, then to access an element you need to dereference the unique pointer and access an offset of this address. If you had a vector instead of the unique pointer, then you'd have to dereference pointer inside the vector and access an offset of this address. In short - I expect exactly the same performance

Comment: I think you may be able to adapt this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41259045/742314 to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful answers. I will relent and use a vector.

Comment: So, how would I instantiate a vector and specify the 'size' constructor parameter? This is obviously wrong: std::vector< circular_buffer<uint32_t> > ringVec(size);

Comment: @DavidA: Pass the desired size and an example item to be copied.  It's constructor #3 here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector   So: `std::vector<circular_buffer<uint32_t>> ringVec(MAX_BUFFERS, circular_buffer<uint32_t>(size));`